# Converting old Opencv code to the new C++ API, replacement for cvGetSubRect?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am converting some old OpenCV code using the C api to the new C++ API in OpenCV 2.3.  I am wondering what the method is to replace the `cvGetSubRect` call is?

I have the following, `cvGetSubRect(some_cv_mat_pointer, another_cv_mat_pointer, some_cv_rect);`

What is the equivalent to this in the C++ api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create an roi on the source image which gives you a new image - there is no actual pixel copying it all happens automatically

```
Mat image(.....)     // original image 
Rect roi(10, 20, 100, 50);     // shape of roi            
Mat image_roi = image(roi);    /// really a window into image, copy it if you need to change it
```

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html

Comment: +1 for mentioning that no data is copied during this procedure.

Comment: Thanks.  And to copy the data (if I need to keep it once the data is deallocated), I would use src.copyTo(dst)?

Comment: Actually, my suggestion for copying doesn't work.  Crashes at runtime... I have a cv::Mat *I; object, along with the rect.  I run cv::Mat tmp_mat = (*I)(rect); tmp_mat.copyTo(*roi_dst_cv_mat_pointer);